# How to generate the n-simplex?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, simplex

I was following this wikipedia [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn), in the simplex article to see if I could create a MATLAB algorithm to generate a simplex with $n$ points in $3$-dimensional space.

Sure enough it works for 4 vectors. The section also says that alternating between the two methods described, one can generalize for any number of vectors (or even dimensions). Thing is, I don't see how that is possible.

Consider $n > 4$, for example 6. Following the method, the fifth and sixth vector would have the same first and second coordinate as vector 3 and 4. One would then use the dot product rule to find the 3rd coordinate for both. In other words, vectors 5 and 6 are identical.

Am I interpreting the algorithm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the $n$-simplex as constructed in the wikipedia section is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, so to construct the six corners of the $5$-simplex, you need Matlab vectors of length $5$.

Comment: Makes sense. How does one generate an n-simplex with vector length of 3?

Comment: The $n$-simplex is an $n$-dimensional object. It cannot be embedded in the $\mathbb R^3$.